# Is it possible to separate source code from documentation comments in Rust?

Tags: documentation, rust

I like good documentations for source code, but I hate the documentation comments in the code. I found solutions to separate the code from the documentation for other languages, but not for Rust. So, is any solution to separate the source code from the documentation in Rust out there?

Comment: If you want the documentation separate, can't you just write it separately in a non-Rust-specific tool?

Comment: I can. Do you know a good tool for that?

Comment: There are lots of good tools, but they're highly specific to personal taste - it isn't really a Rust question anymore.  :-)

Comment: @NorabX If you want to write your doc in markdown files, there is [rust-skeptic](https://github.com/brson/rust-skeptic) to test them.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Many years have passed and this below answer is no longer true. See the comments.

I'm afraid there's none. I am following Rust ecosystem and I have never seen even a mention of anything like that. On related note, I think the comments should be in the code, and if you writing open source code in Rust I'd advise to stick with the standard ways of doing things, just for the sake of other people. Eg. I am a vivid advocate of tab indentation as opposed to spaces ("Indent with tabs, align with spaces"), yet because Rust community settled on (clearly inferior :) ) spaces, I use spaces in my Rust projects. It doesn't fit my preferences, but after getting over it, it makes mine and other people lives easier when cooperating.

As a workaround, I would suggest making your editor just aggressively fold comments.

Comment: That's a real shame! Because I like to separate all coding elements, like tests, code and documentation. I don't understand the convention to write the documentation in the code. Comments for complex functions are helpful, but not the documention comments. I think it makes the code unreadable. Nevertheless , much thanks.

Comment: @NarabX Having the documentation near what it documents also helps keeping it up-to-date. I can very easily imagine someone change the signature of a function and forget to update it in the doc. This problem is mitigated when the doc is 2 lines before the function. And if you find the code unreadable with too much doc, just configure you text editor to fold documentation comments by default :)

Comment: @mcarton I understand what you mean, but as far as my experience goes, people ignore the doc even if it is before the function ;) and sometimes I have no access to my favorite and configured text editor. So, to fold the comments is a good workaround, but it is not what I want. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @NorabX: Note that Rust has a specific trick to help avoiding out-dated code samples => code samples are compiled and tested along the rest of the code.

Comment: There have been plans to let `cargo doc` generate arbitrary markdown, but nobody has been able to land the PR yet.

Comment: It's possible to do with #[doc = macro_invocation!()]. For example with #[doc = include_str!("../../doc/my_smol_example.rs")]